# grails i18n label cross-referencing?

Tags: grails, syntax, internationalization, label

Is it possible to include i18n property values within other internationalized messages in grails?

I have a domain class containing 2 properties, "minDelay" and "maxDelay", and I want to write an internationalized message referencing the labels to both.

I wrote a custom validator (maxDelay must be bigger than or equal to minDelay):

```
maxDelay(validator:{
    value, reference ->
    if (value < reference.minDelay) {
        return ['custom.error', it]
    } else {
        return true;
    }
  })
```

when it fails, I'm printing the property `stub.maxDelay.custom.error`.

In my messages.properties there are the properties:

```
stub.maxDelay.custom.error=Property [{0}] must be bigger than value of minDelay
stub.minDelay.label=Min. delay (ms)
stub.maxDelay.label=Max. delay (ms)
```

How can I use the value of the `stub.minDelay.label` property instead of static text?
The error message should read like:

```
"Property [Max. delay (ms)] must be bigger than value of [Min. delay (ms)]"
```

I've tried referencing it like `{stub.minDelay.label}` or `${stub.minDelay.label}` but all I get is a parse error from grails.

Perhaps I'm approaching this in the wrong way, would it be possible to inject the label via a numeric parameter in the validator? Like for example if the error message were:

```
stub.maxDelay.custom.error=Property [{0}] must be bigger than value of [{1}]
```

Answer (score 0):

Note that there is also third parameter, of class `org.springframework.validation.Errors`, that can be used for fine-tuning your error messages, like:

```
maxDelay(validator:{ value, reference, errors ->
    if (value < reference.minDelay) {
        errors.rejectValue('maxDelay', 'stub.maxDelay.custom.error', [value, obj.minDelay], 'oops')
    }
  })
```

it will work for message:

```
stub.maxDelay.custom.error=Property [{0}] must be bigger than value of [{1}]
```

Comment: No luck, I tried your suggestion and it will render the values of the object's properties, not the label names. Like for example `Property [10] must be bigger than value of [5000]`

Comment: oh, you just need it to be a `Property [Max. delay (ms)] must be bigger than value of [Min. delay (ms)]"`, without values? So why not you just wrote it as is?

Comment: I'm trying to separate the minDelay property label from whatever other messages that refer to it. It'll also be needed for other situations where an i18n message must include other messages in it.